# I don't have an Android device. If shopping questions are off-topic here how on Earth I'll ever have one?

Tags: discussion

Considering you are a good source of information relating anything Android. Do you really suggest that in this most important question of Android life I should resort to those other *not-so-good* forums?

I heard lot's of stories people buying Android devices based on hype, marketing but not thorough research. Which later also found to be bad decisions.

Additional information [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37594/with-which-headset-phone-is-it-possible-to-fast-forward-rewind-audio-tracks-on-t).

Comment: Relevant: [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/371/)

Comment: Good question, nice formulated and relevant! PS, here's some example of a Q for how to research specific stuff. links to Gsmarena: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37588/is-there-a-website-that-displays-android-phone-specs-with-search-criteria-such-a#comment50557_37588

Answer (score 8):

Yes, head over to other places for this question. What's best for you is a matter of your personal taste and preferences. That'll lead to unconstructive discussion and speculation here. We chose to not let that happen on our site. Also note, that the market renews its product lines every few months and that devices are not available everywhere.

We chose to rule such questions out, please accept that.

For all distinctive and constructive questions that are on topic as per the FAQ, feel free to ask.

Example for a personal opinion that may or may not help you:
Get the latest Nexus phone.

Comment: _Get the latest Nexus phone_    It depends. The question is [if it supports the function I need](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37594/with-which-headset-phone-is-it-possible-to-fast-forward-rewind-audio-tracks-on-t) it to support? For the matter of fact is there ANY Android phone on the market that supports the function I want it to support?

Comment: _Yes, head over to other places for this question._ OK. On which of those other forums do I find relevant information on [which phone supports fast forward and rewind via remote control](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37594/with-which-headset-phone-is-it-possible-to-fast-forward-rewind-audio-tracks-on-t), if there is such a phone at all?

Comment: You just put some good examples on *why* we chose the way ce4 wrote: Those answers are *subjective*. Our concern are *objective* answers valid for a wide range of users.

Comment: @superuser If you phrase your question like "How can I fast forward and rewind with a remote control?" it should be on topic. But make sure to be precise about what you want in your question (and title).

Comment: @Izzy: :-) exactly my intention. superuser: Donct be offended by that, it's there for a reason: to keep the quality up. Just look at xda to see where this could end.

Comment: @ce4 I caught that idea behind your words, hence my comment above :) I had the same in mind, couldn't have done it better than you. "Practical lessons" are the best to teach you (which justifies such "traps"). And full ack to your remark to superuser: Don't be offended, we didn't want to trick you for bad -- but giving the example yourself you might easier understand the purpose, that was the idea behind it.